Get output of subproccess in Makefile using zsh
I would like to conditionally execute a Makefile target based on the current OS. I am running MacOS with zshell.
install:
    @uname
    @if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then \
        $(MAKE) install_mac; \
    fi

When I run make install I see uname produces the correct output. But how to capture the output for the conditional? If possible, I would like the Makefile to be able to work with both zsh and bash.
tpulliam@lappy azure-cicd % make install
Darwin

If I copy the if statement into my terminal it works, but for some reason $(uname) returns an empty string when using make.
tpulliam@lappy azure-cicd % if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then \
        echo hi; \            
    fi

hi


I doubt that the shell that Make uses internally is zsh, unless you've set the SHELL Make variable to that shell. This is probably a typo, forgetting that you have to double any shell $ up so that Make doesn't try to expand it as a Make variable.
